# Javascript function & setting $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that gets called from my controller to my service.

```
GridService.getHeaders($scope.grid);
```

Service is below...

```
    function getHeaders(grid){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.put('v1/headers', grid).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I need to get the data I receive from this and set it to a $scope variable in my controller...

```
$scope.headers = (Data from getHeader function)
```

Which will then get injected into this function. Sorry if this all seems confusing... The way I had it originally was just setting

$scope.headers = GridService.getHeaders($scope.grid);

However $scope.headers always returns empty.

```
    function getFullHeaders(headers, highlightFilteredHeader){
        var returnArray = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++ ){
            returnArray.push({
                field: headers[i].key, 
                displayName: headers[i].name,
                enablePaginationControls: true, 
                headerCellClass: highlightFilteredHeader,  
                enableFiltering: true,  
                enableSorting: true, 
                visible: true,  
                filter: { term: "", }
            });
        }

        return returnArray;
}
```

Comment: Try the assignment in .then() callback, something like GridService.getHeaders($scope.grid).then(function(result){$scope.headers=result}, function(error){//error});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getHeaders` method returns a promise. Therefore, if you want to react to the promise being resolved, you have to use `.then(fn)`.

Try:

```
GridService.getHeaders($scope.grid).then(function(response) {
    $scope.headers = response;
});
```

Comment: So can I leave the promise that gets returned in the GridService?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean there, but principally, yes, you could store promises anywhere you want. But don't get me wrong here, you probably shouldn't. You should treat promises as their own special kind. You shouldn't store them longer than they are unresolved.

Comment: Nevermind, however I am getting an unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: GridService.getHeaders($scope.grid)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.headers=response;
            })‌;

Comment: So it is actually calling the GridService.getFullHeaders function first, and $scope.headers is undefined because it actually never made the call for GridService.getHeaders yet

Comment: Without knowing **when** the getFullHeaders function is called, I can not say what the outcome will be. See, the concept of promises is delaying everything in the .then block until your server has responded and the response has been received. It introduces a certain concept of 'time'